# Disable Fans on MacBook Air 2019

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, power-management

Hi I'd like to disable the fans on my 2019 MacBook Air. Since it doesn't even do smth for Pooling since ist completly passive coolen (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiCBYAP_Sgg, Video from Louis Rossmann).
Thx for any Ideas.
(btw i tried smcFanControl and the cli of it)

**I do not recommend this to anyone. I want to know if its possible and not the Risks**

Comment: You might have to elaborate on “smth“ but I’ll get the obvious answer out of the way and let someone else answer how to hack things. Power management may be challenging if the blowers are disabled in a crude mannner. I’m voting +1 not because I agree we should do it, but that it’s fair game to ask how things work and trust people aren’t breaking things maliciously or will start a fire overheating their lithium battery in their Airs and Pros.

Comment: Physically detaching the fans should work. AFAIK you can't disable them software-wise. Out of curiosity, are the fans too loud for you or why do you want to disable them?

Comment: If they dont do anything why let themuse power

Answer (score 2):

Apple sure has listened to this market segment. I would trade that Air for a MacBook (one) or the new Air. Silent running is such a rare pleasure for many portable computers.

I also strongly endorse never disabling fans on gear that depends on them for cooling and safe operation of lithium batteries that are a clear safety hazard if they charge or run over temperature.

Comment: As mentioned by rossmann they do exactly nothing

Comment: Rossmann shows that they aren't connected to the CPU directly - which indeed isn't a good thermal design - however, they will still help a little, since heat will flow through the whole system and not just punctual through the CPU. So they might not be as effective as they could, but I am sure, if they did *nothing*, then Apple would have removed them, simply for cost-effectiveness.

Comment: I want to know if its possible and not the riks, i amaware of those